# How to get all elements in "parentNode" whose id starts with same string?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that gets element's id and finds out its `parentNode`, now I want to find all the elements whose id starts with same `string`, in that `parentNode`.
Is there any function or way to find out that?
I am trying this:

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="someString"]');
```

but this returns me a list of elemets from entire document, but I just want to get the elements from the same `parentNode`.
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Elements have QSA too](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#interface-definitions):

```
var elements = myElement.parentNode.querySelectorAll('*[id^="someString"]');
```